# Open Excel file after successful RDP connection

Tags: php, remote-desktop, microsoft-excel

I have a PHP script that creates RDP files on the fly and it works great.

The next step is to automatically open an Excel file once the RDP session is created, or simply "link" to the Excel file within the RDP connection.

An example would be a user clicks on a link that generates a RDP file which they then open and connect to, which immediately opens file.xlsx in Excel.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Should the users also have the ability to navigate around in the rdp session, or would they be limited to excel? If the latter, check out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226772/can-rdp-clients-launch-remote-applications-and-not-desktops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226772/can-rdp-clients-launch-remote-applications-and-not-desktops)

Comment: @purtip31, even better is to use the remoteapp functionality, though it requires setup on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for a RemoteApp setup?  Do you have RemoteApps defined on the Terminal server?  Or did you want the old style were you just specify the command to run, but you don't have the RemoteApp features?

If you want the old style, just the `AlternateShell` value ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms861803.aspx)) to be the path to excel followed by the path to the document you wanted opened.

Really, you probably should be looking at setting up the RemoteApp functionality though, since it permits the window to be resized and so on.

[RemoteApps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755055.aspx) must be [defined on the server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733174.aspx), and in your configuration, you specify the defined name.  So you might have a setting that looked like this

```
remoteapplicationprogram:s:||Excel_Open_Example_Doc
```

Comment: RemoteApp is definitely the way to go. I set it up and am able to get the RDP files to open the connection to the file. I'll have to play around with the automation aspect of creating the RemoteApps on a per file instance.